# replacing letters with numbers

Tags: php

So i've been trying to get this bit of code to work all day and haven't been able to do it... I wnat to be able to replace letters with a number (or just a value) from an array. this is the code i've got:

```
    $l2n = 
    array(
            'a'=>'1',
            'b'=>'2',
            'c'=>'3',
            'd'=>'4',
            'e'=>'5',
            'f'=>6,
            'g'=>7,
            'h'=>8,
            'i'=>9,
            'j'=>10,
            'k'=>11,
            'l'=>12,
            'm'=>13,
            'n'=>14,
            'o'=>15,
            'p'=>16,
            'q'=>17,
            'r'=>18,
            's'=>19,
            't'=>20,
            'u'=>21,
            'v'=>22,
            'w'=>23,
            'x'=>24,
            'y'=>25,
            'z'=>16
            );
$string = str_split($string);
$explode = array_shift($string);
if($l2n[$explode] == $explode)
{
    echo $l2n[$explode];
}
else
{
    echo $l2n['a'];
}
```

I tried to use Preg_replace but i've never had a good expereince with that function. so If anybody could help me out, hint me in the correct direction, that'd be great.

Comment: [Something really fast :)](https://eval.in/private/ddd8e5eecb988b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `str_replace` once you've used `array_keys` and `array_values` to get each side of the array:

```
$keys = array_keys($l2n);
$values = array_values($l2n);

$yourstring = 'Hello world!';

echo str_replace($keys, $values, $yourstring);

// H5121215 231518124!
```

**Demo**: https://eval.in/77453

**Docs**:

- http://php.net/str_replace
- http://php.net/array_keys
- http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
$string = preg_replace(array_keys($l2n), array_values($l2n), $string);
```

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

> If both pattern and replacement parameters are arrays, each pattern will be replaced by the replacement counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world would you use an array for this? Isn't [ord()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) what you are looking for here?

```
$string = "ABCDE";

foreach ( str_split($string) as $chr ) {
    echo ord($chr) - 64; // or 97 if they all are lowercase
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: The array I gave was just a sample of what I want to do, i'm working on a cipher, and the values cannot be calculated using any other way. Hence the reason I chose an array.

Comment: Fair enough. Go with [scrowle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20460993/1697320) then.